# Python 3 - Formatting print commands

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to python and I'm trying to export some information from network devices and format it into a text file. I have the below code I'm running;

```py
for device in (LD6AGGSW01 , LD6AGGSW02 ):
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
    output = net_connect.send_command('show hostname')
    pickle.dump(output, open("hostname.p", "wb"))
    output = net_connect.send_command('sh ver | i NXOS | i image |i file |i is:')
    output = output.strip()
    pickle.dump(output, open("IOSimage.p", "wb"))
    output = pickle.load(open("hostname.p","rb"))
    print('Hostname: ' + output)
    output = pickle.load(open("IOSimage.p","rb"))
    print(output)
```

I'm trying to change the output from looking like:

```
Hostname: LD6-AGG-SW01 

NXOS image file is: bootflash:///nxos.7.0.3.I3.1.bin
Hostname: LD6-AGG-SW02 

NXOS image file is: bootflash:///nxos.7.0.3.I3.1.bin
```

to:

```
Hostname: LD6-AGG-SW01 
NXOS image file is: bootflash:///nxos.7.0.3.I3.1.bin

Hostname: LD6-AGG-SW02 
NXOS image file is: bootflash:///nxos.7.0.3.I3.1.bin
```

Any ideas on how I'd go about this?

Comment: What's up with the `pickle` stuff?

Comment: If its just printing, you can use "\n" literals to add more linebreaks or check your output print strings and remove excess linebreaks from them

Comment: Debug your code and look at the variables. There are likely some newlines.

Comment: An alternative is to use a "end" print("Hostname:"+output,end="")

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `net_connect.send_command()` returns a string with a trailing newline.

If that's correct,

```py
for device in (LD6AGGSW01 , LD6AGGSW02 ):
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
    hostname = net_connect.send_command('show hostname').strip()
    ios_image = net_connect.send_command('sh ver | i NXOS | i image |i file |i is:').strip()
    print('Hostname:', hostname)
    print('Image:', ios_image)
    print()
```

– i.e. `strip()`ing the outputs – should do the trick.

Comment: Awesome this worked and is so much cleaner! Guess I have a lot to learn - many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.strip()` to remove the unwanted `\n` character in your output:

```py
for device in (LD6AGGSW01 , LD6AGGSW02 ):
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
    output = net_connect.send_command('show hostname')
    pickle.dump(output, open("hostname.p", "wb"))
    output = net_connect.send_command('sh ver | i NXOS | i image |i file |i is:')
    output = output.strip()
    pickle.dump(output, open("IOSimage.p", "wb"))
    output = pickle.load(open("hostname.p","rb"))
    output = output.strip()    # Strip output
    print('Hostname: ' + output)
    output = pickle.load(open("IOSimage.p","rb"))
    output = output.strip()   # Strip output
    print(output)
    print()    # Call print function to insert extra line
```